# Varying HashMap sizes (Java)

Tags: java

I'm loading in a variety of text files that have different lengths and adding them to a HashMap called 'collection'.

```
List<String> textFileList = Arrays.asList("ArsenalNoStopWords.txt", "ChelseaNoStopWords.txt", "LiverpoolNoStopWords.txt",
            "ManchesterUnitedNoStopWords.txt", "ManchesterCityNoStopWords.txt", "TottenhamNoStopWords.txt");

for (String text : textFileList) {
        scanFile(text);
    }

public static void scanFile(String textFileName) {
    try {

        Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(textFileName));

        while (textFile.hasNext()) {
             collection.put(textFile.next().trim(), 0);
        }

        textFile.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After this, I'm loading in one of those documents and counting its frequency of words with the HashMap (collection).

```
ArrayList<Integer> document = new ArrayList<Integer>();

document = processDocument("TottenhamNoStopWords.txt");

private static ArrayList<Integer> processDocument(String inFileName) throws IOException {

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : collection.entrySet()) {
        entry.setValue(0);
    }

    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
    ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(textFile.hasNext()) {
        file.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    for(String word : file) {
        Integer dict = collection.get(word);
        if (!collection.containsKey(word)) {
            collection.put(word, 1); 
        } else {
            collection.put(word, dict + 1);
        }
    }

    textFile.close();

    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(collection.values());
    return values;  
}
```

Following this, I'm outputting the variable values from processDocument() to a text file - I have six, all of which are under different names. Theoretically, each version of the collection for each team should be the same length, as the keys of the collection never change, and are always from the textFileList list - the only variable that changes is the document to be processed. But why is that my vectors (ArrayLists) very in length, when they should be the same size but with varying frequency values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first step you are adding with `textFile.next().trim()` in the second part with `file.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase())`, you have values duplicated in your collection with lowercase and non lower case.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So it's a matter of either adding a `toLowerCase()` method to `textFile.next().trim()`, or removing the `toLowerCase()` method from `file.add(textFile.next().toLowerCase())` to avoid any duplicates?

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni yes.